# Using `conan.cmake` with `conan_multi` generator, missing build_type argument?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I am attempting to get a multi-config cmake build working using [`conan.cmake`](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan). I am also following along with the [`cmake_multi`](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.7/integrations/cmake/cmake_multi_generator.html) docs.

It seems that in the docs for `cmake_multi`, they require that you both pass `-g cmake_multi` and `-s build_type={type}` (`{type} being Release/Debug/...`).

However, in `conan.cmake` it does not look like the current `build_type` is passed on when calling `conan install -g cmake_multi ...`.

I am hitting a situation now where if I run with the configurations `"Release;Debug"` conan reports that a bunch of packages are missing

```
Requirements
    boost/1.71.0@conan/stable from 'my_repo' - Cache
    libconfig/1.6@internal/custom from 'my_repo' - Cache
    ...
Packages
    boost/1.71.0@conan/stable:5b939a5d59f5432d9263459d17f2acb1535629bd - Missing
    libconfig/1.6@internal/custom:ef44119b64b51a15f7b334090b2ff53fddcc38df - Missing
    ...
```

However if I edit `conan.cmake` to also pass `"-sbuild_type=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"` at the end of
`conan_args`, it is able to find my packages for both Release and Debug.

Could anyone see what I may be doing wrong here? I do not specify a `build_type` in my conan profile, nor is one already set as part of my settings.

Comment: Try adding `--build missing`? Conan centre doesn't always have prebuilt debug packages so you need to build them yourself (if i remember correctly the Conan command tells you to do this in its error output)

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for the great suggestion. I added `BUILD missing` (and experimented with `BUILD outdated`) but get error messages during compilation from several packages that `build_type setting should be defined.`

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan, it takes care of this stuff for you

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am! I linked it above in the question, but I guess not super obvious.

Comment: If you're using that you shouldn't need to call Conan at all,cmske should do it for you with the correct parameters, I've used it for multi configuration generators and it just worked without having to do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the source code for `conan.cmake` a few more times I discovered that it is possible to have it propagate the build type, you just need to use the [`PROFILE_AUTO`](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#profile_auto) argument to `conan_cmake_run`.

```
conan_cmake_run(
   PROFILE ${CONAN_PROFILE}
   CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${CONFIGURATION_TYPES}
   PROFILE_AUTO build_type  # Use build_type as detected by CMake, override any values in the profile
   BUILD outdated
)
```